# "Digital Forensics" — on topic here, or create a separate site?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope

There is a proposal currently in evaluation to create a *new* site in the field of digital forensic science:

[**Digital Forensics**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98731?phase=definition)

This *appears* to be a part of "Information Security" but we don't generally want to split apart a site if a proposed subject is already wholly or largely on topic here.

**Please have a look at the "example questions" above** and let me know if they are defining a large ecosystem of questions that are ***not*** already covered here, or if the vast majority of questions would already be welcome on *this* site.

All comments are appreciated. Specific examples (or a question breakdown) of which questions from that proposal would be considered on/off topic would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any aspect of computer forensics that is off-topic for IT Security?](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/631/is-there-any-aspect-of-computer-forensics-that-is-off-topic-for-it-security)

Answer (score 22):

I would definitely say there is an overlap in terms of what is on topic. I've even found some similar questions on our site :

How to identify the presence of rootkits from an image of Linux memory? -> [Are there any artifacts for filesystem forensics in memory?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65797/are-there-any-artifacts-for-filesystem-forensics-in-memory), [How would one know if they have a rootkit?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44208/how-would-one-know-if-they-have-a-rootkit/44209#44209)

How can I read data via ADB if an Android device is turned on but locked? -> [How would one know if they have a rootkit?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44208/how-would-one-know-if-they-have-a-rootkit/44209#44209)

Which Mobile OS has the most attack surfaces for a digital forensics expert to use in order to attempt recovery of encrypted data? -> [Android full disk encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119186/android-full-disk-encryption), [Are there actually any advantages to Android full-disk encryption?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10529/are-there-actually-any-advantages-to-android-full-disk-encryption), [Android L encryption vs. iOS 8 encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68454/android-l-encryption-vs-ios-8-encryption)

Is there a way to image a locked and encrypted iPhone and accessing the data for digital forensic investigation? -> [Bruteforcing an iOS PIN](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102693/bruteforcing-an-ios-pin)

To me it seems that most of their questions would be on topic here. The only issue I see is that they have some subjective career advice and product-recommendation questions, which would be frowned upon here and outright banned for the latter.

Comment: Looks like you copy pasted the same lin (How would one know if...) twice.

Comment: Product recommendations are a bad fit for any SE site, that's a very poor reason for a split.  security + questions that are bad for SE sites is a poor selling point.

Comment: Totally agree with Andre here - there is very little from the proposal scope that would be SE appropriate that wouldn't be in scope here.